# Mostrar datos en una tabla según opción de select seleccionada

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Buenas noches, estoy programando un pequeño sistema, tengo un combobox que es llenado con datos de una tabla de una base de datos en PHPMYADMIN. Y quiero que según la opción seleccionada se muestren unos u otros datos que están almacenados en una tabla llamada Hoteles cuyos campos son: Nombre, Domicilio, Estrellas, Condición en una tabla html.
Este es mi código:

```
<?php

$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost" , "root" , "");
$bd = mysqli_select_db ($conexion, "empresa");

$destinos = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT nombre FROM destinos");



echo ("<select>");
while ($dest = mysqli_fetch_array($destinos)) {
    echo "<option value=".$dest['id'].">".$dest['nombre']."</option>";
}
echo ("</select>");


?>
```

De este modo si yo por ej selecciono la opción 1 se muestra los datos del hotel con la ID 1.

Gracias desde ya

Comment: Deberás de entrar al mundo de `ajax` para poder hacer lo que quieres, mandas llamar con ajax la clase de php que se conecta a la base de datos y te regrese el arreglo con los campos de la tabla y tu los dibujas desde JS

Comment: Es un trabajo de la facultad y no nos han enseñado Ajax. Debe haber forma de hacerlo solo con php.

Comment: Exacto, la mejor opción es Ajax, porque puedes hacerlo todo en background, sin tener que moverte de la página actual. Señalo que en el `SELECT ...` te falta el campo `id`, para poder colocarlo en el `value` de cada `option` y recuperar el valor de id seleccionado usando el evento `on change` desde Ajax.

Comment: Bueno, entonces lo que puedes hacer es desde el mismo php pintar ya las tablas con las consultas, y a todas ponerle el estilo de `display:none` de tal forma que con un evento de `change()` en JS se dispare cada que cambia tu combo box, mostrando la tabla que quieras mostrar según la opción seleccionada.

Comment: Claro que eso implicará que tu página tardará mucho más en cargar en lo que esperas se resuelven las consultas a la base de datos. Y es una forma muy rústica, por no decir impráctica y no recomendada para resolver el problema.

Comment: @Lixus me parece una opción poco performante, sobre todo si se manejan muchos datos y más aún teniendo medios para hacerlo de otra forma. A no ser que se requiera el uso exclusivo de php... lo cual sería algo absurdo... Al OP: Si Ajax te parece como ir a Marte, no te asustes, es muy sencillo hacer lo que se te ha indicado, ejemplos hay de sobra aquí mismo y en Google. Creo que vale la pena aprenderlo, es más, es obligatorio aprenderlo si quieres ahorrarte muchos problemas y crear un programa eficaz.

Comment: @A.Cedano lo se, incluso yo mismo lo comenté, pero si en su escuela no le permiten usar ajax, no veo otra forma de que pueda hacer lo que quiere sin usar ajax.